# SQL server 2014 Transaction Replication

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, transactional-replication

I am trying to replicate a column with data type `char(10)` to another column with datatype `char(30)`

While applying snapshot I get an error saying

```
"Field Size too large"
```

As per my understanding Publisher has size smaller than the Subscriber so why would this error come up?

I tried looking over the internet but could not find much help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff42583d-27ba-4f05-9513-c4764acfad5e/field-size-too-large?forum=sqlreplication) has pointed a similar issue with a resolution:

> I had this same problem.  In comparing the schema of the table in both
>   the publisher and subscriber, they appeared to be identical.  However,
>   I had to drop the table on the subscriber and recreate it using a
>   create table script generated on the publisher.  Once I did that, the
>   snapshot proceeded without any more errors.  HTH.